# How to execute group of threads against the values in csv data set config file

Tags: csv, jmeter, dataset

May I know how to execute each of the thread groups sequentially against the values in csv file?

My scenario is as follows

Lets assume csv file contains

- value 1
- value 2

**Struture of the jmeter script as below**

```
CSV config    
 Thread 1
    -sampler 1      
    -sampler 2    
    -sampler 3

  Thread 2
    -sampler 1

  Thread 3
    -sampler 1
    -sampler 2
```

[image]

What I want is to **execute thread 1,2 and 3 against "value 1" in the csv file. Then run thread 1, 2 and 3 again with "value 2" in the csv file.**

Note - Tried with the "current thread group" option in csv config file but it does not provide the results that I was expecting. (The way it behaves was, thread 1 executed against value 1 and value 2, likewise other threads also executed against value 1 and value 2)

Thank You

Comment: Good question, but can you explain your use case?

Comment: I want to implement a scenario verification, where the scenario should be run against different value sets that are configured in the csv data set config. (setup, verification and teardown tread groups together represent the scenario that I want to verify)

Comment: so you want to run setup, thread group(s) and teardown multiple times? can you edit you question with this flow?

Comment: The point I have highlighted in the question (What I want is to execute thread 1,2 and 3 against "value 1" in the csv file. Then run thread 1, 2 and 3 again with "value 2" in the csv file) is the expectation

Comment: I tried it using the current thread group option and it worked, also using current thread option.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be quite simple if you shifted from Thread Groups to Controllers within the same Thread Group. In other words: express fragments of the script by using proper controllers, as opposed to Thread Groups:

```
Was                            Change to

                               Single Thread Group 
CSV Data Set Config              CSV Data Set Config
Setup Thread Group               Setup (Some Controller)
Verification Thread Group        Verification (Loop Controller)
TearDown                         TearDown (Some Controller)
```

That way `Single Thread Group` loops over CSV data, while `Loop Controller` loops over same number of iterations as currently configured for Verification Thread Group. Both, Setup and TearDown can be configured to run only once pr iteration if needed, and generally everything you can express with Thread Groups, you can also express with Controllers.